# apprequests not working with external website

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, apprequests

I am developing a website which uses the facebook api. I can retrieve my friends, post to my wall, se my photos, all good. but for some reason, when I try to send an app request to my selected friends on the multi friends selector. The invite just doesn't work, it send a request, but the request is broken.

My facebook app has the "Website with Facebook Login", "app on facebook" and "Page tab" set up. My javascript is..

```
function multiFriendSelector(){
    FB.ui({
        method: 'apprequests', 
        message: 'You should learn more about this awesome site.'
    }, requestCallback);

}

function requestCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
    if (response != null && response.request_ids && response.request_ids.length >0) {
        for(var i = 0; i < response.request_ids.length; i++) {
            console.log("Invited: " + response.request_ids[i]);
        }
    } else {
        console.log('No invitations sent');
    }
}
```

My console output is always showing me that none invitation has sent.

I don't know if there is something that I am missing on this. Any of you guys already have faced this?

Thanks

Comment: [This might be the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831890/apprequest-doesnt-send-the-notification/11885672#11885672).

Comment: I saw that post before, as said, I have the canvas set up. It should be another issue. Thank you Lix

Comment: Is your application in sandbox mode?

Comment: That was the problem, the sandbox was enabled and it was blocking the invite to people who wasn't app devs. Thank you so much @Lix